# Delete object in C#

Tags: c#, .net

In dotNET we could write unmanaged code, where can I allocate memory dynamically (by keywords: stackalloc, new), use pointers etc.
It's possible to free memory (for example by something like delete in C++)?

Comment: Please show an example. This is kind of vague at the moment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648560/allocating-unmanaged-memory-in-c-sharp the mashler will free memory when it leaves scope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends **how** you allocate memory.

For example, if you allocate memory with [AllocHGlobal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cyb68cy.aspx) :

```
double* vertices = (double*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(
                          3 * count *  Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(double)));
```

You allocate the array of doubles of a given size.

To free that memory after you have to call [FreeHGlobal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freehglobal.aspx)

```
 Marshal.FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)vertices);
```

There are also other functions for allocating COM task memory, like

[AllocCoTaskMem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.alloccotaskmem.aspx) and relative [FreeCoTaskMem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freecotaskmem.aspx)

Comment: Five answers in five minutes and only one of them understand the question? :) +1 for you.

Answer (score -1):

try with this code in order to free

```
Marshal.FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)vertices);
```

Comment: That has nothing whatsoever to do with the question.

Comment: Never call GC.Collect(). Well, almost never.

Comment: I know Henk but i tell that's possible, Thank's for your help that's nice

Comment: Don't reuse your "answer" to write a completely different answer. Instead remove your old answer and write a new one if you change your mind.

Comment: Zano I'don't know that's prohibited to correct answer, i'am sorry

Comment: Don't be sorry :-) It's not prohibited to correct an answer, but you changed the answer completely, which invalidates all the comments. In that case it's more practical to write a new question.