# Manual Memory Paging in the .Net Framework (Is it possible / How?)

Tags: c#, memory-management, clr, ramdisk

I have a major interest in writing a database management system.  Having read a few pages about how SQL Server 2000 was implemented, I discovered that 4KB memory pages were used, each being a direct copy of a 4KB page on the hard disk.  These pages were loaded into RAM as needed, and then lazily wrote back to disk when they fell idle (oversimplification).

Being in the planning stage of my project, I am wondering if this level of control is possible in code running on the CLR.  I realize that C, C++, or [D](http://dlang.org/) is probably a better fit for this task, but I would like to prove that to myself first.  Part of the motivation behind this is that I would eventually like to actually override the CLR Garbage Collector with my own, using my database as the heap, at least for relatively stale objects.

Is it possible to directly control memory from the CLR?  If so, how would I do this?

Assume for now that my data is a bunch of 256 byte wide structs/classes, stored in a flat table on disk, and I'm using 64KB pages.

Comment: Possibly related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648560/allocating-unmanaged-memory-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of.  You can use [memory mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) in .NET so that writing to "memory" is really writing to disk.

Comment: Thanks for that link; it is informative.  That gives me another good way to think about this problem.  My first reaction is that I want to manage that interaction myself, but I may get over that.

Comment: SQL Server does some very low-level things with memory paging--it really does its only virtual memory management.  That's something you can't do in .NET.